# What does it take to replicate the mysql, 'mysql' database correctly?

Tags: mysql, gtid

I've searched for a while and I am having trouble finding anything that even addresses my situation.

I have need to replicate the 'user' table specifically, from my master cluster to my async slave.

I can create working replication for databases besides the 'mysql' database, but when I attempt to replicate the mysql database replication appears to stop working for every database.

I have really hit a wall, especially since the 'show slave status' command reports that 'Slave_IO_Running' and 'Slave_SQL_Running' are both 'Yes'

The executed gtid set even matches when I view 'show master status'.

I believe the error is within when I configure the slave, or how I am replicating the mysql db.

I am doing

```
mysqldump --databases ${databases[@]} --single-transaction --triggers --routines --events --host=${MYSQL_TARGET} --port=${MYSQL_TARGET_PORT} --user=${MYSQL_BACKUP_USER} --password=${MYSQL_BACKUP_PASSWORD} > /tmp/dump.sql

mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock < /tmp/dump.sql && break  
mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -e "reset master;"

mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -e "CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='"${MYSQL_TARGET}"',MASTER_PORT="${MYSQL_TARGET_PORT}",MASTER_USER='"${MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER}"',MASTER_PASSWORD='"${MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD}"',MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1;"
mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -e "start slave;"
```

where databases is an array of databases I want to replicate including the mysql database.

I also include this in my cnf file, which to my understanding will replicated only the user table in the 'mysql' database, and everything in

```
replicate-do-db=<user database>
replicate-do-db=mysql
replicate-do-table=mysql.user
```

I don't see anything in the error log that suggests what I am doing is broken either.  I have ensured the replication user and password is the same on the master as the slave, so that the credentials don't change when the user table is replicated.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "master cluster"?  What versions of MySQL are on master and slave?

Comment: Hi Rick, 

Thanks for the response!  When I refer to the master cluster, the architecture is there is a Galera cluster in USW2.  The async read only slave lives in the local data center.  

The Mysql Version on the slaveis 
Server version: 5.7.20-19-log Percona Server (GPL), Release '19', Revision '3c5d3e5d53c'

The mysql version on the master cluster is 
Server version: 5.7.20-18-57-log Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL) Release rel18, Revision 4a4da7e,

Comment: If you are replicating `GRANT` information, then apply the `GRANTs`; do not `UPDATE` or `INSERT` into the `mysql` tables.